# How to create emulators with small screen size

Tags: android

Hello i'm testing my application with different screen densities. I have created 4 emulators with low medium high and extra high density and a normal screen size but the screens doesn't have the same size. I specified in the launch options Screen Size (in) = 3.7 and Monitor dpi = 113 i'm using a Mac Book Pro 1280 x 800 13".

Can that be done?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow the instructions here: http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/managing-avds.html

- In skin, check "Resolution" and add the resolution you want.
- In hardware, add the required dpi.

The screen size will be determined by these two factors as detailed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel_density#Calculation_of_monitor_PPI

**Make sure you use the dpi values of the device you want to emulate, not the values from your monitor.**

For a list of screen sizes and resolutions, check http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_displays_by_pixel_density (it includes your monitor, although that information is irrelevant for the emulator)